# refresh listview with broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I have listview where i view a list of objects. This list is saved in the internal memory, and will be refreshed when you start your app with a service. But when you open the listviewactivity, i want the listviewactivity to restart if the service is finished loading.

I tried to implement it like this:

in my service class, after it is ready:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("REFRESH_RECEIPT_LISTVIEW"));
```

and then at the bottom of my ListViewActivity.class:

```
class DataUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals("REFRESH_RECEIPT_LISTVIEW")) {
            //restart code 
         }

    }
}
```

So this should work, but i don't get how to restart my listviewactivity with the broadcast receiver. To restart an activity you can do something 
start new activity, same as old one, finish this one

but how can i do this within the broadcastreceiver context?
And do i need to initialize/start my receiver within my listviewactivity oncreate or so?

thanks!

Comment: Why 'restart' your activity? You could just refresh your ListView's adpater with the updated data.

Comment: Okay fair point, but how to refresh my adapter from another class? - in this case t]he broadcastreceiver class

Comment: If i read your question correctly, the `DataUpdateReceiver` is an inner class of your `ListViewActivity` ("*..and then at the bottom of my ListViewActivity.class...*"). This means that the `DataUpdateReceiver` has access to your `ListViewActivity`'s fields/members. If one of these fields is the adapter, then the `DataUpdateReceiver` can use it to update the adapter.

Comment: thank you for your insights, indeed it works like a charm now. I misplaced my close-class-body-bracket and hereby it was no longer an inner class and i could not acces the adapter. Now this is repaired.